# Custom event in Vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm not understanding the Custom Event in Vuejs2.

I have a component named as `user-navbar` which contains a dropdown menu, when change I execute this method:

```
handleCurrentServerChange: function(name, zoneid, currency_name) {
    /* Code omitted */
    this.$emit('server-changed', { serverznid: zoneid });
},
```

Which emit an event called `server-changed` and I want to listen to this event  in another component `accounts-linked`.

```
 <accounts-linked inline-template :server_data="server_data" @server-changed="handleServer">
```

When the event is emitted I should call the method `handleServer`. But isn't working. This is the method:

```
handleServer: function(value) {
                alert(value);
}
```

I got few errors

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "handleServer" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "server-changed": got undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the `server-changed` event triggered, `<account-linked>` component should have `handleServer` declared within `methods: {...}` as event handler, but i can't see it.

Comment: Oops! @Xlee Edited. I just keep "handleNewMessage" but even if I put handleServer, I get the same errors.

Comment: Do you use SFC(single file component) in Vue2? You use `<template>` or the render (with JSX) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `server-changed` event can only be caught in the parent of `user-navbar`, like this:

```
<template>
    <user-navbar @server-changed="handleServer"></user-navbar>
</template>
```

If `accounts-linked` is not the parent of `user-navbar`, you will want to use a [non-parent-child communication strategy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication), as outlined in the Vue.js docs.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for what @exclsr mentionted I found this [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dreampie/h1j8oa5L/2/) and apply that on my code:

app.js

```
Vue.use({
install(V) {
    let bus = new Vue();
    V.prototype.$bus = bus;
    V.bus = bus;
}     
});
```

In the components:

```
this.$bus.$emit('server-changed', 1);
this.$bus.$on('server-changed', this.handleServer);
```

Working perfectly now! :)

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you got it to work! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this as the answer to your question, to help people who have similar questions in the future.